# Android OpenCV UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, opencv

I use OpenCV in android and some clients get that error UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1.

I use init method in onResume():

```
if (OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback)) {
        ((App)getApplication()).setIsOpenCVInitialized(true);
    } else {
        ((FaxApp)getApplication()).setIsOpenCVInitialized(false);
    }
```

The imread function is called from the next activity onCreate method.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: onCreate() gets called, before onResume() finished ?

Comment: but onCreate the next activity, initAsync is called in the previous activity

Comment: move imshow() out of onCreate(), again, you can't run any opencv code, before the libs were loaded ( mLoaderCallback finished )

Comment: But I check if the opencv is initialized before I run that method.

Comment: that only checks, if it was successfully started, not finished ( async problem )

Comment: you've got to check for LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS inside the BaseLoaderCallback

Comment: I had this callback, but I didn't set there my IsOpenCVInitialized variable, I try it now. Thanks.

Comment: @berak I think your solution works, so you can write it as an answer and I can accept it.